# pd.read_html() not reading date

Tags: python, parsing, wikipedia

When I try to parse a wiki page for its tables, the tables are read correctly except for the date of birth column, which comes back as empty. Is there a workaround for this? I've tried using beautiful soup but I get the same result.
The code I've used is as follows:

```
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2002_FIFA_World_Cup_squads'
pd.read_html(url)
```

Here's an image of one of the tables in question:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution can be alter the page content with `beautifulsoup` and then load it to `pandas`:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2002_FIFA_World_Cup_squads"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

# select correct table, here I select the first one:
tbl = soup.select("table")[0]

# remove the (aged XX) part:
for td in tbl.select("td:nth-of-type(3)"):
    td.string = td.contents[-1].split("(")[0]

df = pd.read_html(str(tbl))[0]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    No. Pos.               Player Date of birth (age)  Caps               Club
0     1   GK      Thomas Sørensen        12 June 1976    14         Sunderland
1     2   MF         Stig Tøfting      14 August 1969    36   Bolton Wanderers
2     3   DF       René Henriksen      27 August 1969    39      Panathinaikos
3     4   DF       Martin Laursen        26 July 1977    15              Milan
4     5   DF      Jan Heintze (c)      17 August 1963    83      PSV Eindhoven
5     6   DF        Thomas Helveg        24 June 1971    67              Milan
6     7   MF      Thomas Gravesen       11 March 1976    22            Everton
7     8   MF      Jesper Grønkjær      12 August 1977    25            Chelsea
8     9   FW    Jon Dahl Tomasson      29 August 1976    38          Feyenoord
9    10   MF     Martin Jørgensen      6 October 1975    32            Udinese
10   11   FW            Ebbe Sand        19 July 1972    44         Schalke 04
11   12   DF        Niclas Jensen      17 August 1974     8    Manchester City
12   13   DF         Steven Lustü       13 April 1971     4                Lyn
13   14   MF         Claus Jensen       29 April 1977    13  Charlton Athletic
14   15   MF       Jan Michaelsen    28 November 1970    11      Panathinaikos
15   16   GK           Peter Kjær     5 November 1965     4           Aberdeen
16   17   MF    Christian Poulsen    28 February 1980     3         Copenhagen
17   18   FW    Peter Løvenkrands     29 January 1980     4            Rangers
18   19   MF     Dennis Rommedahl        22 July 1978    19      PSV Eindhoven
19   20   DF      Kasper Bøgelund      8 October 1980     2      PSV Eindhoven
20   21   FW         Peter Madsen       26 April 1978     4            Brøndby
21   22   GK  Jesper Christiansen       24 April 1978     0              Vejle
22   23   MF  Brian Steen Nielsen    28 December 1968    65           Malmö FF
```

Comment: Yeah, this did the trick. Thanks! Is there a way to get all tables from the page or would it be best to do a for loop?

Comment: @EAG The easiest way would be using loop with `pd.read_html` and then concat the dataframes together with `pd.concat`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the parse_dates parameter to True inside read_html method.

Comment: Yeah, I previously tried that but it didn't work. I think the (aged xx) part of the date might be causing the problem